Installing Ubuntu 24.04.01 on Virtual box in MAC M2
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04.01 server edition on virutal box in MAC M2 but I'm getting this error message I'm getting this error 0% [ Connecting to ports.ubuntu.com] when try to run sudo apt upgrade . i can ping 8.8.8.8 . Thanks for your help and support

What's the full output?

run , sudo apt upgrade and get this error 0% [ Connecting to ports.ubuntu.com]

That is not an error message, and it is not the full output.
